Как лучше хранить оптимизированные изображения для вёрстки?
Дело в том, что на одно изображение из макета в целях оптимизации сайта приходится хранить минимум 9 файлов:

исходное
x2 и x3 размеры для retina-дисплеев
webp и avif версии всех предыдущих изображений.

То есть к примеру из одного маленького hero.jpg мы получаем следующее:

hero.jpg
hero@2.jpg
hero@3.jpg
hero.webp
hero@2.webp
hero@3.webp
hero.avif
hero@2.avif
hero@3.avif

(9 файлов на одно изображение, и это ещё без mozjpeg и адаптивных картинок под разные разрешения).
И тут возникает резонный вопрос - как хранить всё это многообразие, неужели просто в одной папке ./images? Ведь даже из 10 картинок в макете (а это на минуточку уровень небольшого лендинга) уже получается минимум 90 файлов.

Не нравится в одной, разбейте по подпапкам с каким то логическим названием

Ну 90 для 10 и что? У вас предел 65535, а может и больше, в зависимости от операционной системы.

Мой личный опыт показал, что вариант изображения сразу в x2, чтобы под ретину, в webp и оптимизированным через сервис tinypng - хватает за глаза.
